# Django Lettuce Running Tests Twice in Parallel

Tags: python, django, integration-testing, lettuce

I'm trying to get some output from my step definitions with Lettuce.  When I run the test, I see it flash my output for a second, before being overwritten by what appears to the same tests.  However I can see the steps being called twice in the output.  One it is very dark (almost black) colored, another time it's green or red.  The output is highlighted below.  [image: phantom tests]

This is causing me a headache because the debugging info is showing up in the other test thats running, not this one.  I'm having a hard time articulating this, but I think the screen capture helps illustrate the point: I should only see each step get called once, which isn't the case right now.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**Feature**

```
Feature: Navigation
As a persion looking for information on specific machine
In order to view up to date machine inventory
I should be able to navigate to a individual machine

Background:
    Given the following users exist:
        | username | first_name | last_name | password |
        | johndoe  | John       | Doe       | testpass |
    And the following machines exist:
        | msnbr     | machine_name     | brand_name | brand_slug | division | product_group | machine_type | price | model  | location |
        | 111111    | Router           | Altendorf  | altendorf  | All      | All           | All          | 100   | model7 | Zenith   |
        | 222222    | CNC Router       | Belfab     | belfab     | All      | All           | All          | 200   | model6 | Echo     |
        | 333333    | Saw              | Durst      | durst      | All      | All           | All          | 300   | model5 | Xalpha   |
        | 444444    | Another Router   | Belfab     | belfab     | All      | All           | All          | 250   | model4 | Beta     |
        | 555555    | eh Router        | Belfab     | belfab     | All      | All           | All          | 250   | model4 | Water    |
        | 666666    | Router 6         | Belfab     | belfab     | All      | All           | All          | 250   | model2 | River    |
        | 777777    | Router 8         | Belfab     | belfab     | All      | All           | All          | 250   | model1 | Snake    |
    And I am logged in as "johndoe" with password "testpass"

Scenario: As an executive, I can see all brands
    Given I see "Brand"
    Then I should see "Altendorf"
    And I should see "Belfab"
    And I should see "Durst"
    Then I click "Logout"

Scenario: As an executive, I can navigate into brands
    Given I see "Brand"
    When I click "Belfab"
    Then I should see "5" machines
    And the machines should be in the following order:
        | model  |
        | model2 |
        | model4 |
        | model5 |
        | model6 |
        | model7 |
```

**Steps (formatting is bit off)**

```
from lettuce import step, world
from lettuce_webdriver.util import assert_true
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from website.factories import *
from website.models import *

@step(u'the following machines exist:')
def the_following_machines_exist(step):
for machine_hash in step.hashes:
    brand, created = Brand.objects.get_or_create(
        name=machine_hash['brand_name'],
        slug=machine_hash['brand_slug']
    )

    division, created = Division.objects.get_or_create(
        name=machine_hash['division']
    )

    product_group, created = ProductGroup.objects.get_or_create(
        name=machine_hash['product_group']
    )

    machine_type, created = MachineType.objects.get_or_create(
        name=machine_hash['machine_type']
    )

    machine = Machine(
        machine_year = "2000",
        hold_for = "john",
        us_destination = "el paso",
        voltage = "500",
        last_update_on = "January 10",
        port_of_entry = "LAX",
        msnbr = machine_hash['msnbr'],
        description = "Machine description",
        location=machine_hash['location'],
        model=machine_hash['model'],
        age=15,
        price=machine_hash['price'],
        active=True,
        division=division,
        product_group=product_group,
        machine_type=machine_type,
        brand=brand
    )
    machine.save()

@step(u'I should see "([^"]*)" machines')
def i_should_see_n_machines(step, n):
selector = "#left-main ol li"
elements = world.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
if len(elements) != int(n):
    raise Exception("Error: Number of machines does not match: %d != %d" % (len(elements), int(n)))

@step(u'the machines should be in the following order:')
def the_machines_should_be_in_the_following_order(step):
selector = "#left-main ol li"
elements = world.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
for i in range(0, len(elements)):
    el_text = elements[i].find_element_by_css_selector(".name").text
    if step.hashes[i]['model'] != el_text:
        print "FAIL"
    else:
        print el_text
        print step.hashes[i]['model']
```

**Settings**

```
# Django settings for stiles_aml project.
import os.path
root = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace('\\','/')

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = ( *** )

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = { *** }

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Detroit'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = root + '/../media/'

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = root + '/../static/'

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    root + "/../shared_static",
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '***'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = '***_aml.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = '***_aml.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    root + '/../templates'
)

# Sentry key
SENTRY_DSN = '****'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.humanize',

    # 3rd party
    'south',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'tastypie',
    'django_extensions',
    'shell_plus',
    'raven.contrib.django',
    'django_nose',
    'lettuce.django',

    # Authored
    'website',
)

# Email settings
EMAIL_HOST = '****'
REQUEST_QUOTE_EMAIL = ['****']
```

Comment: I have the same and I believe it's an artifact of how lettuce_webdriver is set up. It's difficult to tell from your screenshot though.